# Cypress: store value in a variable

Tags: cypress

I want to store a td value in a variable. Why this code doesn't work?

```
let storedValue;
cy.get('tbody>tr:nth-child(1)>td:nth-child(3)').invoke('text').then(text => 
{
  storedValue = text;
})
cy.contains(storedValue).should('exist');
```

It returns "cy.contains() can only accept a string, number or regular expression"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach would be to use `aliases`.

```js
cy.get('tbody>tr:nth-child(1)>td:nth-child(3)').invoke('text').as('storedValue')

cy.get('@storedValue').then((storedValue) => {
  //Access storedValue here
  cy.log(storedValue) //prints value
})
```

Or if you just want to check whether the element exists or not, you can directly do:

```js
cy.get('tbody>tr:nth-child(1)>td:nth-child(3)').should('exist')
```

And for the question of why is your code not working, its because javascript works asynchronously, so instead of the code that gets the text first, the contains statement is executed first and the reason it fails is that `storedValue` doesn't have anything in it, in short, it is `undefined`. To fix then you have to add `then()` so that the code runs in a sequence we intend it to run in.

```js
let storedValue
cy.get('tbody>tr:nth-child(1)>td:nth-child(3)')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    storedValue = text
  })
  .then(() => {
    cy.contains(storedValue).should('exist')
  })
```

Comment: you don't need 
` .then(() => {
    cy.contains(storedValue).should('exist')
  })
` you can do it in the previous one